# class functions with constant object parameter?

Tags: c++, function, class

My assignment requires that I write a program that performs the rational number operations addition, subtraction, multiplication and division on two fractions. They must be class objects with variables numerator and denominator. I am given a header that I may not change:

```
class Rational
{

    private:
        int numer;
        int denom;
    public:
        Rational();
        Rational(int);
        Rational(int, int);
        const Rational add(const Rational &) const;
        const Rational subtract(const Rational &) const;
        const Rational multiply(const Rational &) const;
        const Rational divide(const Rational &) const;
        void display() const;
};
```

For example, if given fractions a, b, and c, I must multiply a with b and store it in c:

```
c = a.multiply(b)
```

The function definition I've come up with is something like

```
const Rational Rational::multiply(const Rational &) const
{
   return a.numer*numer, a.denom*denom;
}
```

The object `a` is undefined in the function, but I have no other ideas as to how I can pass in a class object as a variable and multiply it to another class.

Comment: Name your parameter: `const Rational Rational::multiply(const Rational & a) const`. Use your constructor: `return Rational (a.numer*numer, a.denom*denom);`

Answer (score 2):

1. Give the parameter a name,
2. Correctly construct the result object and return it.

   ```
   const Rational Rational::multiply(const Rational & a) const
   {
      return {a.numer*numer, a.denom*denom};
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the two-parameter class constructor in your return statement.

```
return Rational(a.numer*numer, a.denom*denom);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Rational Rational::multiply(const Rational & rhs) const
{
   return Rational{numer * rhs.numer, denom * rhs.denom};
}
```